# Extracting change in polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have 2 shapefiles with interlocking polygons (sadly not with any unique common denominator like fid), one with moved borders. I want to extract the changes made in one of the shapefiles (see picture for clarity) and wondered if that is somehow possible in QGIS

[image: How can I get the extracted area]

Comment: Take a look at [Vector Overlays](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html)

Comment: Do you have any (even on unique) field ?  Also, what are the possible changes ? External boundary is always unchanged on only the inner polygons (limited to 2 ?) can change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do: create a 3rd layer as the `Intersection` of the two other ones (`before`and `after`)

[image]

[image]

[image]

With one expression in the `Intersection` layer, you can test:

`(overlay_contains('after') or overlay_contains('before'))=0`

When used with rule-based styling, this is what you will get:

[image]

Hope this covers the possible changes in your use case. It is based on testing if a geometry from the Intersect corresponds to either a shape from the `before` or `after` layers. If not, then it's an area where the polygons have been modified